# Adding new line in error-message for vaadin form validation

Tags: java, forms, formatting, vaadin, android-binder

I have a form fields binded to java entity model. That model has an annotation:

```
@ValidPassword
private String password
```

which validates the field with some conditions and return error message containing each failed condition separated by '\n' new line sign.

Vaadin form is connected to this model with:

```
    username =  new TextField("Username");
    username.addClassName("username-field");
    password =  new PasswordField("Password");
    password.addClassName("password-field");
    binder.forField(username ).asRequired().bind("username");
    binder.forField(password).asRequired().bind("password");
```

Writting input to password field results in:
[image-link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcPJ3.png)
When I want each failed condition to start on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [JSR-303 Bean validation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-beans.html#using-jsr-303-bean-validation) with Vaadin 8 or like Vaadin 14 and newer, then you need to use `BeanValidationBinder` instead of regular `Binder`. Also in that case you are not supposed to build bindings using

```
binder.forField(password).asRequired().bind("password");
```

But instead just use

```
binder.bindInstanceFields(form);
```

Furthermore, if you need to customize how error is being displayed, you can use for example [ValidationStatusHandler](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-validation.html#customizing-validation-error-messages), which is called each time validation status changes from valid to invalid or vica versa. By default the error is shown inlined in component. You can define your own component, e.g. `Html`, where you can use rich formatting.

```
    binder.forField(field).withValidationStatusHandler(handler -> {
        if (handler.isError()) {
            handler.getMessage().ifPresent(error -> {
                Html html = new Html("<span>"+error+"</span>");
                layout.add(html);
            });
        }
    }).bind("property");
```

Comment: I use `BeanValidationBinder`. I changed the way of binding to `binder.bindInstanceFields(form);` but the message format is still the same.  I have message from Passay validator joined by '\n' but it doesn't create new lines in the view. How to achive that?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification, I added that part to the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is some kind of workaround, thank you. Is there a way to insert that message to `<div part="error-message">` in password component or manipulate it directly there to show formatted text in place like in the attached image?